# New prompt line not automatically put to command line upon exit code

Tags: command-line, prompt, exit, exit-status

When submitting jobs, I'm getting Exit codes returned, but I have to hit the return key for them to be printed to the log.

```
1. prompt_line/location sas query.sas &
2. [1] 66682
3. prompt_line/location
4. [1]+  Exit 1                  nice -n 19 opt/sas/sashome/server/SASFoundation/9.4/sas 99query.sas
5. prompt_line/location
```

- I submit the sas code 'query.sas' (line 1).
- (Line 2) is put to the command line instantly confirming I've submitted the job and a new prompt line (line 3) is put to the command line instantly also.
- I then have to hit the return key for the Exit status to be put to the command line (line 4) and a new prompt line is put to (line 5).

Where 'sas' is an alias for

```
nice -n 19 opt/sas/sashome/server/SASFoundation/9.4/sas
```

Is there a way to have a new prompt line put to the command line when an exit status is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `sh`-compatible shell as your interactive shell (such as `bash`), you may use `set -b`:

> Report the status of terminated background jobs
>                         immediately, rather than before the next primary prompt.
>                         This is effective only when job control is enabled.

In `bash`, this is equivalent to `set -o notify`.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I am using a bash as you said (but I'm quite new). Where would I add `set -b` ?

Comment: @JackOsborne You could either just type it in at the command prompt, or add it in your `.bashrc` file if you want it to always be active.  You may turn the option off with `set +b`.